# How to make d3 milestone Shape

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to align a down triangle with a rectangle to make a group that can be used to represent a milestone.  Any ideas why this code only shows 2 triangles and how to move them to centre bottom of rectangle or any other methods to achieve the same goal?

http://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/Pej4M/

```
 tri.enter().append("path")
       .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-down"))
       .style("fill", "black")
       .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + xRange(d.start) + "," + yRange(d.Duration) + ")"; });
```

Comment: xAxis and yAxis are also `path`s so the first two triangle data are bound to axis. You can see that if you comment out axis code.

Comment: Point made.  Is there a workaround?  I need both axis and path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the reason you're seeing only two rectangles is that some of the data is bound to existing paths. To fix, assign a special class to the symbols that you can select by:

```
var tri = vis.selectAll("path.tri").data(datar);
```

For the positioning of the symbols, you need to use the same values you use for the rectangles. The y position needs to be offset by a constant so that the symbols appear at the bottom and the x position by half the duration -- I'm guessing that this is what you really want to show as you're currrently hardcoding everything to length 50.

```
.attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + (xRange(d.start) + 25) + "," + (yRange(d.start) + 15) + ")"; });
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pej4M/1/).

Comment: Thanks.  I was close to your suggestion with this http://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/DZmR4/.  Is this the best way to do this?  Transitions are getting very complicated!

Comment: You could group the boxes and triangles in a `g` element.